# Using Source Tree, rebase with conflict, rebase doesn't work after conflict resovled

Tags: git, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm using [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) as my git tool on Windows.

I have a *main* branch and a *feature* branch and I can't get SourceTree to perform a rebase when I have a conflict.

*main* looks like:

> c1 -> c2 -> c4 -> c5

*feature* looks like:

> c1-> c2 -> c3

I want to rebase *feature* so it will be:

> c1 -> c2-> c4-> c5-> c3

There is a conflict between *c3* and *c5*.  I can resolve the conflict, but when I commit the changes I get a *HEAD* tag and looking at my graph I can see that *feature* branch wasn't rebased.

How can I get the rebase to work?

Comment: Just to check: Did you do a `git rebase --continue` after fixing the conflict?

Comment: @Robert - No, I clicked the 'commit' button.

Comment: I don't know about graphical interfaces to git, but the command line workflow would be to fix the conflict, add it to the index with `git add` and then continue rebasing with `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: In a moment of doubt, go to console and write `git status` and it will guide you (in this case `git status` will tell you "resolve conflicts and type `git merge --continue`

Answer (score 179, accepted):

Unfortunately the UX path for the resolving conflicts during a rebase is quite poor in [atlassian-sourcetree](/questions/tagged/atlassian-sourcetree).

After you have resolved the conflict and have all of your changes in the staging area, instead of clicking *commit*, go to *Actions*-> *Continue Rebase*:

[image]

Comment: It means you are done resolving conflicts and you want to continue the rebase

Comment: Note that "have all of your changes in the staging area" is very important. I had resolved all conflicts, but some of the changes where not in the staging area. Sourcetree just seemed to do nothing while a command line `git rebase --continue` showed the proper warning message.

Comment: After resolving conflicts in sourcetree, `git rebase --continue` in bash would give a prompt that a `git add` is needed. While this answer must be the expected way to continue a rebase with the GUI of sourcetree.

Comment: Can't find any such option in SourceTree > Actions in MacOS

Comment: Wow this is such a bad UX. It stages most of the files which makes you think that you should commit them to finish the rebase. It even lets you commit! Ugh. Still I mostly blame git for being insane.

Comment: @Timmmm - ya, agree SourceTree could be a lot better at helping users understand what's going.

Comment: Uff this was helpfull! Switched to sourcetree 2 months ago and could not figure out how to to a good rebase with merge conflicts...

Comment: I've raised an issue, feel free to vote/comment if you want this improved in SourceTree: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-7761

Comment: This is ridiculous, it should automatically continue as you as you marked it as resolved. GitKraken is way more inuitive for rebasing and it's much faster and smoother of a process. But at least this answer works, and is good to know.

Answer (score 9):

> After you have resolved the conflict and have all of your changes in
> the staging area, instead of clicking commit, go to Actions-> Continue
> Rebase:

In the latest version of source tree, after you have resolved the conflict and have all of your changes in the staging area, you have to commit first and then click on *Actions -> Continue Rebase*.

Lastly, you will see numbers near of Pull/Push buttons. It is normal. Just right click on your branch and select ***"force push"*** option to push your code. If you do not see "*force push*" option, you have to activate it on sourcetree.