# Cannot Git Rebase using Sourcetree when solving conflicts

Tags: git, rebase, atlassian-sourcetree

Sourcetree version: 3.3.9 Windows 10.

The situation is:
[image: The historic looks like this]

I want to rebase branch2 to get the changes made in Feature to keep working on Branch2.

I checkout to branch2, right click Feature/Training and click "Rebase current changes onto feature training"

Then I dont know why I get a detatched head with uncommitted changes:
[image]

But I follow the steps indicated here in the official page (https://www.coursera.org/lecture/version-control-with-git/sourcetree-rebasing-Miziw) which say that I have to resolve the conflicts, stage them and NOT commit, I do it.

Then I go to actions, continue Rebase, as all the articles say that is the step to follow.
and then finnally I get this error... can anybody help me please?
[image]

P.S: I already saw this post ([Using Source Tree, rebase with conflict, rebase doesn't work after conflict resovled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887799/using-source-tree-rebase-with-conflict-rebase-doesnt-work-after-conflict-reso)) which is the same problem, but I cant solve it with the answer given, as I did it correctly.

Comment: You might need to open the command line for this one, then. Maybe a bug in SourceTree? From the command line, change directories to your repo, then run `git rebase --continue`.

Comment: Yep, that was the workaround that I had to do... so sad that Sourcetree has this bug in a basic feature...